# Cartan matrices of Schurian algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices

A finite dimensional quiver algebra $A$ is called Schurian in case between two points $i$ and $j$ there is at most one path. Equivalently the Cartan matrix $C_A$ of $A$ has only entries 0 or 1. Here the Cartan matrix of a finite dimensional quiver algebra has entries $a_{i,j}$ the number of paths from point $i$ to $j$. Eilenberg proved that the Cartan determinant (=determinant of the Cartan matrix) of an algebra with finite global dimension is either 1 or -1 and the Cartan determinant conjecture states that it cant be -1.

> Question 1: Is the Cartan determinant conjecture known for Schurian algebras? That is, does a Schurian algebra of finite global dimension have Cartan determinant 1?
>
> Question 2: Which 0-1 matrices are realisable as a Cartan matrix of a Schurian algebra of finite global dimension? Is every 0-1 matrix with determinant 1 and having all diagonal entries equal to one the Cartan matrix of a Schurian algebra?